# Web crawler for sound search. Extracting audio from flash

Tags: flash, search, audio, web-crawler

If i would like to create web crawling cluster searching for sound files (wav, mp3, wma, ...), the main problem i would hit would be the fact that most of sounds in web is wrapped into flash. Flash sends an HTTP request to an mp3 file when user press some play button. Can someone suggest a thinking vector for that kind of problem?